# Git pull - error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:

Tags: git, github

I keep getting this error when I do a git pull every 60 seconds on my monitoring server.  I am using chef and a python script to "git pull" every 60 seconds.

```
Updating 70fe6e8..2da34fc
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    rtb_redis_connections/redis_connections.pyc
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

How do I deal with this?  these pyc files keep getting created.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

My guess is that someone else has accidentally committed this file. How to resolve this:

Remove your local .pyc file

```
rm rtb_redis_connections/redis_connections.pyc
```

Do the pull

```
git pull
```

Remove the file from git and push up the changes

```
git rm rtb_redis_connections/redis_connections.pyc
git commit -m "Remove pyc file"
git push origin master
```

Assuming that you are working on the master branch that is.

Comment: This is my preferred method for taking out unwanted files like logs, fast. Just remove, and commit. Thanks.

Comment: @Magnus_Skog I was also able to use your solution, thank you. Is there a more sustainable way to manage this, other than just yelling at the other developers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Saved me some vital time.

Comment: @usumoio Sure. You could add a `*.pyc` line to `.gitignore` to prevent people from committing it in the first place. Cheers.

Answer (score 5):

> Please move or remove them before you can merge.
>
> Aborting

The solution is actually very simple:

```
git clean  -d  -fx ""
```

- X - delete ignore file has not identified for git files
- D -- deletion was not added to the git in the path of the file
- F - forced operation

Comment: dot't use this is delete all .gitignore file in your local repo.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you put them to `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 1):

You either need to add te `rtb_redis_connections` directory to the repository so that it tracks to the remote, or add the files or directory to `.gitignore`.

Comment: I do have *.pyc in .gitignore

Comment: @Tampa Then maybe someone else committed the `redis_connections.pyc` file by accident.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
git config --global core.trustctime false
```

Comment: Explanation should be provided with the command you mentioned above.